# How do I write a GridFSFile object into a ByteArrayOutputStream object?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, outputstream, gridfs

There was an easy way to do it with gridFSDBFile, but not anymore.

```
//This used to return a GridFSDBFile type. Returns GridFSFile now.
GridFSFile gridFsFile = gridFsTemplate.findOne(new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(idTemp)));
//And would be done this way. Not anymore.
gridFSFile.writeTo(outputstream)
```

The main goal is to return an image saved in the database to display it on an html page as follows.

```
response.getOutputStream().write(outputstream.toByteArray());
response.getOutputStream().close();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have got the same issue while migrating spring 1.x to 2.x. Here is the fix.

```
InputStream iStream =  gridFsTemplate.getResource(gridFSFile).getInputStream();

byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(iStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am probably late, but you can chain an InputStream to OutputStream.

So you can use the following:

```
GridFSFile gridFsFile = gridFsTemplate.findOne(...);
gridFsTemplate.getResource(gridFsFile).getInputStream().transferTo(outputStream);
```